Why can't we zoom more on OSM?
On OpenStreetMap's default viewer, we are limited in zooming, and we cannot zoom more than this.
Why? How to change this, for example, to see the detail of the geometry of some buildings?
Example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/284089#map=19/48.96017/2.58822
Context: for example, with this limitation, it is impossible to precisely measure the dimensions of a building, whereas the information itself is quite precise in the databases. With the OSM UI/UX, the precision is +- 2 meters, whereas in the state databases (which OSM probably reuses), if I remember well, in some regions it can be as accurate as +- 5 centimeters.


it comes down to the number of tiles needed at zoom level 19 it is 274,877,906,944 and zoom 20 has 1,099,511,627,776 that is a lot more processing and storage which costs money. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

@Mapperz Maybe you can copy your comment to an answer?

@Basj you might be better off downloading vector files from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/ile-de-france.html and using QGIS to zoom in as much as you want to measure your buildings.

If you write the application yourself it is possible to overzoom by the client code and stretch the last available raster tile level https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100162.

@Mapperz is it as simple as downloading QGIS, the OSM vector files, and then opening these vector files in QGIS? (I never used the latter)?

yes the shapefile needs to be unzipped https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/ile-de-france-latest-free.shp.zip then load the building file into QGIS.

@user30184 Why do you think the OSM client prevents zooming a few times more? I don't see reasons to block it, but maybe is there one? Do you know where is the OSM client github, so that I can ask in an issue or pull request to add more zooming in the default OSM client?

BTW @user30184, what is the JS library that renders the map on https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/284089#map=19/48.96017/2.58822? Is it leaflet? (I thought it was, but I don't see the leaflet mention in the bottom right footer..)

@Basj That's because there is nothing to zoom to. What openstreetmap.org shows is not the actual data, but prerendered map-images of that data, see Mapperz 1st comment. You can of course zoom an image, but it will just become more pixelated, you don't get to see more details. And it doesn't work as in those movies where you can say: "Computer, enhance image"

BTW, there are projects that render vector data in the browser, rather than images. For instance MapTiler. These will let you zoom in more

@Berend I'm speaking about vector data, not bitmaps. See the screenshot I have posted. When you zoom, we're not zooming on a bitmap which can become pixelated, we're zooming on a vector image. You can say "Computer, zoom x10 on this vector image, and it works" ;) Vector inside®, No pixelation guaranteed™.

@Basj Your screen shot from https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/284089#map=19/48.96017/2.58822 definitely comes from raster tiles, you can see that in the browser debugger network section. This is one of the tiles: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/19/265914/180140.png

@TomazicM Then I'm plain wrong in my previous comment ;) My bad! Why do non-image vector maps are rasterized, instead of rendered on the canvas from vector points?

Because that used to be the fastest way to show a map. When this viewer was build, browsers weren't able to cope with all that vector data. And the canvas didn't even exist in html, so vector data, if any, had to be rendered in the DOM somehow

Because rasters are very easy to cut to pieces/tiles. Its more complicated to cut vector data to tiles and then style them on client side. See example of OSM vector tiles here https://openmaptiles.org/osm2vectortiles/ and for zoom over 21 here: https://data.maptiler.com/downloads/dataset/osm/#21.43/48.96017/2.58822

@Berend Oh that's right about html <canvas>. Does this mean a new version 100% (without old browser support) based on vector points instead of rasterized tiles could give a more performant map and with k times less data traffic to servers: just vector coords instead of bitmaps? Does this exist?  (k = probably between 2 and 10)

See the page I linked to in an earlier comment

With regard to "the number of tiles needed at zoom level 19", I run a raster tile server for UK/IE and generate tiles to 23.  I monitor disk space for each tile zoom level, and the disk usage in order is 16.17,15,18,14,21,13,22,12,23,20,19...  Zoom 20 is 1/20 of the usage of zoom 16.  If you don't discourage scrapers you'll get more higher zoom level usage of course.

Please post this feedback as an answer @SomeoneElse, it's really interesting data for future reference!

I don't think my comment above would make sense as an answer because it's not really an answer to the original question.  That would require someone from the style to say "we only support up to 19 because of $design_consideration" or the ops team to say "... because of some operational consideration".

As all geometries are normally simplified you won't gain much in higher zooms.
And most buildings are not mapped with e.g. a chimney outside a wall or protusions in a wall, etc.
E.g. in regard to your example, this link here: https://www.osmap.uk/larger-text/#21/48.96020/2.58806 shows that you do not gain much more information about those buildings (this is a zoom 20 retina tile "reused" as a zoom 21 standard raster tile). And while some vector maps let you zoom much higher, the vector tiles are actually zoom 14 or zoom 15 tiles overzoomed in most of the cases (but due to their dimensions those zoom 14 vector tiles do equal an e.g. zoom 19 raster tile).
But some vector based maps seem to use a higher precision, e.g. the transport layer: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=21/48.96022/2.58795&layers=T which is produced by Thunderforest, that does use a technique to rasterize vector tiles.
You might also want to check this link (MapComplete indoor map viewer): https://mapcomplete.org/indoors?z=24&lat=48.96025040409242&lon=2.587999948835545 that shows a higher precision at upper zoom levels.

you won't gain much in higher zooms: this is subjective, and depends on the application. Example: there are some details in the buildings (see middle-right of my screenshot), and let's say you want to draw a polygon on top of the map, to calculate the area of some parts, then in this case, it would be useful to have x5 more zoom.

This here might also be helpful: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=21/48.96022/2.58795&layers=T where you see the edges in building walls not simplified to a 90 degree edge. That is vector based map rasterized, I cannot tell about the level of precision the underlining vector system works with, you would have to ask Thunderforest about that.

This is very interesting @crnm! I think you should edit and include this as the answer :) This seems to authorize much more zooming. What's the difference between my original link and yours, only the &layer=T in the URL? What's the name of your map, what is layers=T exactly? Thanks!

Layer T is the transport layer by Thunderforest. I found another example with the indoor map viewer by streetcomplete.org, example link: https://mapcomplete.org/indoors?z=22&lat=48.96023032844434&lon=2.588036939215044 but this does seem simplified as well.

What is Thunerforest @crnm, in a few words?

Thunderforest is a map tile provider that produces the transport layer that you see as the layer T (Transport) at the openstreetmap.org website.

I've added the Transport layer example as well as the MapComplete indoor map viewer example to the answer as those two might be helpful.


Context: for example, with this limitation, it is impossible to
precisely measure the dimensions of a building, whereas the
information itself is quite precise in the databases.

Don't use rendered raster tiles for measuring. Use raw OSM data instead.
